# TensorFlow installation on Windows fails with AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install TensorFlow on Windows 10 using the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

and I am encountering the following error:

```
Using cached tensorflow-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting backports.weakref==1.0rc1 (from tensorflow)
Downloading backports.weakref-1.0rc1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorflow)
Downloading Markdown-2.6.8.tar.gz (307kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 317kB 1.2MB/s
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
self.setup_py, self.name,
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
import setuptools  # noqa
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from setuptools.extension import Extension
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <module>
from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 17, in <module>
import pkg_resources
File "c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1519, in <module>
 register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
 AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

I have the following python and pip version:

```
C:\Users\sukhpreet.singh>python --version
Python 3.6.1
C:\Users\sukhpreet.singh>pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from c:\users\sukhpreet.singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#installing_with_native_pip):

> TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows.